# Dedicated MySql server works with app engine

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I know AppEngine application runs in a restricted "[sandbox](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/)" environment so that it can access limited resources like

> request execution time limit 60 sec (which is for speed optimization purpose)
>   read from external file but can not write ,etc

AppEngine provides a good high replication Datastore ,which is so good to store data but it is hard to mange number of quires  to perform simple operation like insert, update, delete and update as it uses NoSql(basically jpa and jdo).

Because of this we decide to go with Mysql,I know google itself provide cloud sql instance which 
uses Mysql5.6 ,I searched alot on SO and in some post I found that it is possible with some restriction while some post says it is not possible because of limitation of sandbox environment,so it is confusing .

During development one can use local mysql instance as detail provide on this [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/) ,but we want to use External mysql instance which is hosted on ourserver

It possible use Dedicated (External/Local) MySql server with app engine(for production not for development)?

thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: No. And I can't imagine why you would want to. You'd be negating all the advantages of using GAE. Use the datastore, or Cloud SQL.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman  thanks for your answer,app we are working of makes lots of quries to datastore/mysql which we think can exceed app engine data store daily limit ofcause we can purchse quota from google ,but rather why we don't your local mysql server for our detabase.Can you please tell me why we can't use dedicated mysql server,in development mode we can user local Mysql server so why not during live project on app engine?????

Comment: you can do that, but with other providers such as AWS. You can just rent a box and do what you like with it.

Comment: Becsuse only http(s) connections are allowed. Write a service that wraps your sql and access it from there. Bad idea thou to use an external sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google App Engine has a socket API that allows outbound sockets for paid apps, so it is possible to use an external MySQL service. To do this, follow the instructions at the link you provide, but *always* use the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` JDBC driver, and a URL like `jdbc:mysql://your_external_mysql_server:3306/database_name?user=your_user&password=1234`. Ensure your external MySQL server has port 3306 open.

As mentioned by others this may not be advisable as it will have substantially worse performance that the Datastore or Google Cloud SQL.  You will also lose the reliability and scaling that Google App Engine brings.  Moreover hosting a dedicated MySQL instance and paying for bandwidth to it is likely to end up more expensive than simply using Datastore or Cloud SQL.

Comment: Regarding ["Socket Java API"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/) usage, "instructions" of Google Cloud are very scarce:
In [this sample on Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-sockets-python-java-go/blob/master/java_socket_demo/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/demos/sockets/WhoIsClientServlet.java#L73), I see only `new Socket(...)` calls.
What is really needed to open socket(s) to external server, especially to MySQL server through JDBC driver ?

Thanks in advance for your answer !

Comment: App Engine provides the socket API using the standard java Socket class. Reference for this is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html, and there are many tutorials such as https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/. The use has some limits, mentioned in our docs.

To use JDBC to connect externally you don't need to call the Socket api directly - just use jdbc normall as in my answer.