# Using an external MySQL server on Appengine?

Tags: mysql, django, google-app-engine

So I just developed a small app locally, using an external MySQL server. Deployed it to AppEngine and it gave me an error about how it can't find a module name MySQLdb. (backend was
`'django.db.backends.mysql'`)

I switched the backend to  `google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms` but I'm still unable to access the database since I get an error: `Exception Value: You must specify a 'INSTANCE' for database 'default'`.

Is it impossible to use any other MySQL server except CloudSQL?!

(I know about djangoappengine, but it gave me a lot of problems in a previous project so I don't want to go down that route)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dedicated MySql server works with app engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444573/dedicated-mysql-server-works-with-app-engine)

Answer (score 0):

you can run your MySQL server on your own vm (compute engine), in the same project as your app-engine.
You will have to [run it with static IP](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#staticnetworkaddress) to be able to address it.